# How can I make application components swipeable in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm learning how to build mobile applications with React Native and I'm following a React native course by Programming with Mosh. However, I ran into a problem where I can't get my program to allow me to swipe left to delete a list item. Swiping left should open up a red square.

I have tried reading the documentation, googling answers and watching youtube videos, but I have made 0 progress :(.

Here's my code for the ListItem component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

import colors from '../config/colors';
import AppText from './AppText';


function ListItem({title, subTitle, image, onPress, renderRightActions}) {
    return (
        <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
            <TouchableHighlight 
                underlayColor={colors.lightGrey}
                onPress={onPress}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
                    <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                        <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
                        <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </Swipeable>
    );
}
```

and here is the code for when I actually use it:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native';

import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';
import Screen from '../components/Screen';
import ListItemSeperator from '../components/ListItemSeperator';
import ListItemDeleteAction from '../components/ListItemDeleteAction';

function MessagesScreen(props) {
    return (
        <Screen>
            <FlatList
                data={messages}
                keyExtractor={message => message.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({item}) => 
                    <ListItem
                        title={item.title}
                        subTitle={item.description}
                        image={item.image}
                        onPress={() => console.log('message selected', item)}
                        renderRightActions={ListItemDeleteAction}/>
                    }
            ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeperator}
            />
        </Screen>
```

Where the renderRightActions={ListItemDeleteAction} is just another component which holds a View with some style:

```
function ListItemDeleteAction(props) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}></View>
    );
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipeout - We use this library. Although it seems outdated, it still works for us till today.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the library out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to use GestureHandlerRootView to wrap everything!

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import colors from '../config/colors';
import AppText from './AppText';


function ListItem({title, subTitle, image, onPress, renderRightActions}) {
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <Swipeable renderRightActions={renderRightActions}>
                <TouchableHighlight 
                    underlayColor={colors.lightGrey}
                    onPress={onPress}>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Image style={styles.image} source={image} />
                        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                            <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
                            <AppText style={styles.subTitle}>{subTitle}</AppText>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </Swipeable>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}
```

Now the component works on android.